# JSON (GLib) serialization leaks memory for a GHashTable

Tags: c, memory-leaks, glib, gobject

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize a `GHashTable` in and out of JSON and `valgrind` reports memory that is definitely lost as a result of doing this. There are suppressions for `g_hash_table_new` in the `glib.suppressions` file that they distribute, but none for `g_hash_table_new_full` which is what I see a bunch of. My hash table is a `GObject` property that has been set using `g_param_spec_pointer`, and the function to serialize it is:

```
static JsonNode *
foo_obj_serialize_property (JsonSerializable *serializable,
                            const gchar      *name,
                            const GValue     *value,
                            GParamSpec       *pspec)
{
  JsonNode *retval = NULL;

  if (g_strcmp0 (name, "list") == 0)
    {
      GHashTable *list = NULL;
      GHashTableIter iter;
      JsonArray *arr = NULL;
      gpointer key, val;

      retval = json_node_new (JSON_NODE_ARRAY);

      g_return_val_if_fail (value != NULL, retval);
      g_return_val_if_fail (G_VALUE_HOLDS_POINTER (value), retval);

      list = g_value_get_pointer (value);

      arr = json_array_new ();

      if (list != NULL)
        {
          g_hash_table_iter_init (&iter, list);
          while (g_hash_table_iter_next (&iter, &key, &val))
            {
              JsonNode *node = NULL;
              JsonObject *obj = NULL;
              FooItem *item;

              item = FOO_ITEM (val);
              node = json_gobject_serialize (G_OBJECT (item));

              if (JSON_NODE_HOLDS_OBJECT (node))
                {
                  obj = json_node_get_object (node);
                  json_array_add_object_element (arr, obj);
                }
            }
        }

      json_node_take_array (retval, arr);
    }

  return retval;
}
```

the deserialize is:

```
static gboolean
foo_obj_deserialize_property (JsonSerializable *serializable,
                              const gchar      *name,
                              GValue           *value,
                              GParamSpec       *pspec,
                              JsonNode         *property_node)
{
  gboolean retval = FALSE;

  if (g_strcmp0 (name, "list") == 0)
    {
      GHashTable *list;
      JsonArray *arr;

      arr = json_node_get_array (property_node);
      list = g_hash_table_new_full (g_str_hash,
                                    g_str_equal,
                                    g_free,
                                    NULL);

      for (gint i = 0; i < json_array_get_length (arr); i++)
        {
          g_autoptr (FooItem) item = NULL;
          JsonNode *node = NULL;

          node = json_array_get_element (arr, i);

          item = FOO_ITEM (json_gobject_deserialize (FOO_TYPE_ITEM, node));
          g_return_val_if_fail (FOO_IS_ITEM (item), FALSE);
          g_object_ref (item);
          g_hash_table_insert (list,
                               g_strdup (foo_item_get_key (item)),
                               item);
        }

      g_value_set_pointer (value, list);

      retval = TRUE;
    }

  return retval;
}
```

my `GObject` class property get/set functions are:

```
static void
foo_obj_get_property (GObject    *object,
                      guint       prop_id,
                      GValue     *value,
                      GParamSpec *pspec)
{
  FooObj *self = FOO_OBJ (object);

  switch (prop_id)
    {
    case PROP_LIST:
      g_value_set_pointer (value, self->list);
      break;

    default:
      G_OBJECT_WARN_INVALID_PROPERTY_ID (object, prop_id, pspec);
    }
}

static void
foo_obj_set_property (GObject      *object,
                      guint         prop_id,
                      const GValue *value,
                      GParamSpec   *pspec)
{
  FooObj *self = FOO_OBJ (object);

  switch (prop_id)
    {
    case PROP_LIST:
      foo_obj_set_list (self, g_value_get_pointer (value));
      break;

    default:
      G_OBJECT_WARN_INVALID_PROPERTY_ID (object, prop_id, pspec);
    }
}
```

and finally the class getter/setter:

```
GHashTable *
foo_obj_get_list (FooObj *self)
{
  GHashTable *list;

  g_return_val_if_fail (FOO_IS_OBJ (self), NULL);

  g_object_get (self, "list", &list, NULL);

  return list;
}

void
foo_obj_set_list (FooObj     *self,
                  GHashTable *list)
{
  g_return_if_fail (FOO_IS_OBJ (self));

  if (self->list == list)
    return;

  if (list)
    g_hash_table_ref (list);

  if (self->list)
    g_hash_table_unref (self->list);

  self->list = list;

  g_object_notify_by_pspec (G_OBJECT (self), properties [PROP_LIST]);
}
```

I'm running a memory check using `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --leak-resolution=high --num-callers=20 --suppressions=../tests/glib.supp foo`, and I get messages for lost memory for serialize showing:

```
==24303== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,029 of 1,852
==24303==    at 0x483877F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==24303==    by 0x494CAB1: g_malloc (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6000.4)
==24303==    by 0x492C8E4: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6000.4)
==24303==    by 0x4933839: g_slice_alloc0 (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6000.4)
==24303==    by 0x4D72CEE: json_node_alloc (in /usr/lib/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0.400.4)
==24303==    by 0x4D72D37: json_node_new (in /usr/lib/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0.400.4)
==24303==    by 0x4D77B37: json_gobject_serialize (in /usr/lib/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0.400.4)
==24303==    by 0x4867AC9: foo_item_serialize_property (foo-item.c:71)
==24303==    by 0x4D779C1: ??? (in /usr/lib/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0.400.4)
==24303==    by 0x4D77B42: json_gobject_serialize (in /usr/lib/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0.400.4)
==24303==    by 0x4861681: foo_obj_serialize_property (foo-obj.c:146)
==24303==    by 0x4D779C1: ??? (in /usr/lib/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0.400.4)
==24303==    by 0x4D77B42: json_gobject_serialize (in /usr/lib/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0.400.4)
==24303==    by 0x4D77B82: json_gobject_to_data (in /usr/lib/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0.400.4)
```

and for deserialize:

```
==24303== 184 (88 direct, 96 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,774 of 1,852
==24303==    at 0x483877F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==24303==    by 0x494CAB1: g_malloc (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6000.4)
==24303==    by 0x492C8E4: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6000.4)
==24303==    by 0x4966C5E: g_hash_table_new_full (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6000.4)
==24303==    by 0x4861AB2: foo_obj_deserialize_property (foo-obj.c:264)
==24303==    by 0x4D77F00: ??? (in /usr/lib/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0.400.4)
==24303==    by 0x4D7826B: json_gobject_from_data (in /usr/lib/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0.400.4)
==24303==    by 0x4862BEE: foo_obj_deserialize (foo-obj.c:472)
```

I'm having a hard time seeing what I've missed, and various attempts to clear pointers result in a double free or error about ref count == 0. I know there's a lot of `GLib` suppressions because of how it handles memory but I don't know if these fall under that.

I could probably box the hash table and simplify serialization by registering a function with `json-glib`, but I don't want to go that direction unless I need to.

Answer (score 2):

```
node = json_gobject_serialize (G_OBJECT (item));
```

After this line you do nothing with `node`, neither store it somewhere, nor free. This results in leaking memory. Also  note, that `JsonNode` is a `GBoxed`, not `GObject`. Use [json-node-free](https://developer.gnome.org/json-glib/1.2/json-glib-JSON-Node.html#json-node-free) to free it.

---

I'd also suggest you read about reference counting and [analysing valgrind output](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.interpret).

> The stack trace tells you where the leaked memory was allocated. Memcheck cannot tell you why the memory leaked, unfortunately.

For `deserialize` method it was allocated at (foo-obj.c:264), that's `g_hash_table_new_full`. You create a hash table, but don't destroy it.

Comment: If you're referring to `foo_obj_serialize_property` thd line `obj = json_node_get_object (node);` follows which uses `node`. If I free `node` as suggested I get an error about ref count but changing that to `json_node_dup_object` fixes that and any remaining leaks in serializing. Deserializing is what's producing the `valgrind` messages that I'm not sure of still.